# oracle query on time

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Query:

```
SELECT col1 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE TRUNC(created_date) = TRUNC(sysdate)
```

If the query take 10 minutes to execute and query was run @ 11.55 PM -- What will be the result of query?  Will the query return data, on `created_date` when query is submitted or when the result is received or depends on some other factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the data as of the date that the query was submitted in this case.